# Importing irregular data in r

Tags: r, import, format

Im hoping someone can help me with a data import question, I think it may be an easy fix, but haven't found the answer.  I have a large number of txt files containing antenna scans and I need to import them in a uniform configuration.  The problem is that they all contain an irregular number of lines of diagnostic data about the antenna before the actual data starts.  I need a function that can identify when the actual data begins, so I can then import it with the correct data in the correct columns.  Basically, for each file, I need to identify the number of lines of diagnostic code, so I can specify skip=" " when inputing the file with read.delim or something similar.

Heres an example of one of the files that I'm talking about:

```
Power OFF @ 12:05:50 02/15/13 
Power ON  @ 12:06:03 02/15/13 
Reader #1 12:06:03 02/15/13 

Reader #2 12:06:03 02/15/13 

Battery Voltage = 13.35 @ 13:00:00 02/15/13 
Battery Voltage = 13.42 @ 14:00:00 02/15/13 
Battery Voltage = 13.32 @ 15:00:00 02/15/13 
Battery Voltage = 13.55 @ 16:00:00 02/15/13 

Reader #2 02:57:40 02/17/13 LA 900 226000012999

Reader #2 02:57:40 02/17/13 LA 900 226000012999

Reader #2 02:57:40 02/17/13 LA 900 226000012999

Reader #2 02:57:40 02/17/13 LA 900 226000012999
```

Comment: so what data do you need from that file

Comment: The data that starts after the battery voltage reads, i.e. reader #, time, date, tag number

Comment: what about `rl <- readLines('file.txt'); rl <- rl[grepl('Reader\\s+#\\d+\\s+[0-9:]+\\s+[0-9/]+\\s+.+$', rl)]; read.table(text = rl, comment.char = '', colClasses = 'character')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slight variation. This will return every line that begins with *Reader* and contains 7 elements separated by spaces. I noticed that the first two *Reader* lines were shorter, if this isn't always the case then this will of course not work.

```
antenna0 <- readLines("antenna.txt")
antenna0 <- antenna0[grep("^Reader", antenna0)]
antenna <- strsplit(antenna0, " ")
data.frame(do.call(rbind, antenna[sapply(antenna, length) == 7]))

#      X1 X2       X3       X4 X5  X6           X7
#1 Reader #2 02:57:40 02/17/13 LA 900 226000012999
#2 Reader #2 02:57:40 02/17/13 LA 900 226000012999
#3 Reader #2 02:57:40 02/17/13 LA 900 226000012999
#4 Reader #2 02:57:40 02/17/13 LA 900 226000012999
```

I suppose you could do this directly in `grep` using more advanced regular expressions, but I don't have the chops.

edit:

Slight improvement relying more on `grep`:

```
antenna0 <- readLines("antenna.txt")
antenna1 <- antenna0[grep("^Reader.*[\\s{4,}]", antenna0)]
antenna2 <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(antenna1, " "))
data.frame(antenna3)

#      X1 X2       X3       X4 X5  X6           X7
#1 Reader #2 02:57:40 02/17/13 LA 900 226000012999
#2 Reader #2 02:57:40 02/17/13 LA 900 226000012999
#3 Reader #2 02:57:40 02/17/13 LA 900 226000012999
#4 Reader #2 02:57:40 02/17/13 LA 900 226000012999
```

Short explainer:

`[\\s{4,}]` means that any character string containing spaces (`\\s`) of four or more in number (`{4,}`) will be returned.

`^Reader` means that any character string starting with the letter sequence *Reader* will be returned.

`.*` combines the two patterns, functioning as an AND operator.

Answer (score 2):

#### `read.table`

If you use `readLines` to read in the text line-by-line, you can use `grep` to search for the highest line number that matches "Battery Voltage" and use that for `skip`.

```
read.table(file.txt, 
           skip = max(grep('Battery Voltage', readLines(file.txt))), 
           # set comment delimiting character to anything besides "#"
           comment.char = '')
##       V1 V2       V3       V4 V5  V6       V7
## 1 Reader #2 02:57:40 02/17/13 LA 900 2.26e+11
## 2 Reader #2 02:57:40 02/17/13 LA 900 2.26e+11
## 3 Reader #2 02:57:40 02/17/13 LA 900 2.26e+11
## 4 Reader #2 02:57:40 02/17/13 LA 900 2.26e+11
```

Note that a further cleaning (combining columns, formatting dates) is necessary.

---

#### `read.fwf`

It may make more sense to use `read.fwf` (**f**ixed **w**idth **f**ile) if column widths are consistent. You'll need to use `na.omit`, `complete.cases`, or some other means of getting rid of blank lines, as `read.fwf` doesn't accept a `blank.lines.skip` parameter like `read.table` and its variants:

```
na.omit(read.fwf(file.txt, 
                 widths = c(9, -1, 17, -1, 2, -1, 3, -1, 12), 
                 skip = max(grep('Battery Voltage', readLines(file.txt))), 
                 comment.char = ''))
##          V1                V2 V3  V4       V5
## 2 Reader #2 02:57:40 02/17/13 LA 900 2.26e+11
## 4 Reader #2 02:57:40 02/17/13 LA 900 2.26e+11
## 6 Reader #2 02:57:40 02/17/13 LA 900 2.26e+11
## 8 Reader #2 02:57:40 02/17/13 LA 900 2.26e+11
```

However, counting characters to figure out column widths is a pain (and error-prone).

---

#### `readr::read_fwf`

The `readr` package makes dealing with fixed-width files slightly less annoying, and gives useful warnings when things aren't getting parsed ideally. It also provides parameters to parse dates and datetimes as you read in your data, which is convenient:

```
library(readr)

df <- read_fwf(file.txt, 
               fwf_widths(c(9, 18, 3, 4, NA)), 
               col_types = list('c', col_datetime('%H:%M:%S %m/%d/%y'),'c', 'i', 'd'), 
               skip = max(grep('Battery Voltage', readLines(file.txt))))

df <- df[complete.cases(df), ]
# or df <- na.omit(df)
# or if some NAs are possible, more robust:
# df <- df[colSums(!apply(df, 1, is.na)) > 0, ]

df
## # A tibble: 4 x 5
##          X1                  X2    X3    X4       X5
##       <chr>              <time> <chr> <int>    <dbl>
## 1 Reader #2 2013-02-17 02:57:40    LA   900 2.26e+11
## 2 Reader #2 2013-02-17 02:57:40    LA   900 2.26e+11
## 3 Reader #2 2013-02-17 02:57:40    LA   900 2.26e+11
## 4 Reader #2 2013-02-17 02:57:40    LA   900 2.26e+11
```

Note the nicely parsed datetime and slightly simpler input method for column widths (you can let it guess with `fwf_empty`, which works well if you have column names).

If you've got your widths and column types correct, anything incorrect will be entered as `NA`, so if you use `na.omit`, you may be able to avoid a `skip` parameter altogether:

```
na.omit(read_fwf(file.txt, 
                 fwf_widths(c(9, 18, 3, 4, 13)), 
                 col_types = list('c', col_datetime('%H:%M:%S %m/%d/%y'),'c', 'i', 'd')))
## # A tibble: 4 x 5
##          X1                  X2    X3    X4       X5
##       <chr>              <time> <chr> <int>    <dbl>
## 1 Reader #2 2013-02-17 02:57:40    LA   900 2.26e+11
## 2 Reader #2 2013-02-17 02:57:40    LA   900 2.26e+11
## 3 Reader #2 2013-02-17 02:57:40    LA   900 2.26e+11
## 4 Reader #2 2013-02-17 02:57:40    LA   900 2.26e+11
```

This approach is somewhat precarious, though, so should only be used if you can verify that it's working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you always looking for the first line after the last line with "Battery Voltage"? If so, try this:

```
the.file <- readLines("C:\\Users\\myfile.txt")
row.to.begin.skip.at <- tail(grep("Battery Voltage", the.file), 1)
```

Then set `skip=row.to.begin.skip.at` in you preferred reading function. The grep() function here searches each line for the phrase "Battery Voltage" then returns a list of all row numbers with that phrase in it. The tail( , 1) function returns the last row with the phrase in it.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  In my case, I'm actually trying to figure something out that will identify the pattern of the data I want.  This is due to the fact there are a number of diagnostic readouts in various files in addition to the battery voltages.

Answer (score 0):

You could read the file as a block of text and use `grep` to identify the lines you want to get rid off. Here, I stored your block of text in `test.txt`. Let's say your header goes all the way to the `Battery Voltage` part, you could first identify the line numbers that contain `Battery` and then find the last instance of it. That will be the number of lines to skip.

```
con = file('test.txt', 'r')
text = readLines(con)
close(con)

lines_to_skip = max(grep('Battery',text))
```

You should then read your data just fine.

```
> x = read.table('test.txt', skip=lines_to_skip, sep=' ', comment.char='')
> x
  V1     V2       V3       V4 V5  V6       V7
1 Reader #2 02:57:40 02/17/13 LA 900 2.26e+11
2 Reader #2 02:57:40 02/17/13 LA 900 2.26e+11
3 Reader #2 02:57:40 02/17/13 LA 900 2.26e+11
4 Reader #2 02:57:40 02/17/13 LA 900 2.26e+11
```

Comment: Thanks, that does work in this instance.  But I have thousands of these files, and the diagnostics are not always just battery voltage reads (just happened to be the start of the one I pasted).  There is a number of diagnostic readouts, so I was hoping to find something to identify the pattern of the data I want to start at.  Thanks for the input though, I really appreciate it

Comment: In that case, you could use the same approach but instead of using `grep` on what you don't want, you use it to find what you want. For example, you are interested in the lines with **Reader** because they contain the data you want, but in your example there seems to be some lines that start with **Reader** in your header. To get rid of those, you could use `strsplit` on each row and count the number of elements. If it has 7 elements, you know that this is your main data. If it only has 4, it's junk so do not start your `read.table` yet.